# After Triggering the code, the Master workbook also getting closed without saving the file

Tags: excel, vba

```
Option Explicit

Sub combine()

Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim lr As Long
Dim ln As Long
Dim i As Integer


Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False


Set wbk = ThisWorkbook

wbk.Activate

lr = wbk.Sheets("Gov 1.01 Report").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
ln = wbk.Sheets("Gov 1.01 Report").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim fDialog As FileDialog
    Dim filename As String
    
    Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fDialog
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Title = "Please select the files"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "All supported files", "*.xls*"
        .Filters.Add "Excel files", "*.xls*"
        
        If .Show = True Then
            For i = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
            'Opening selected file
        filename = .SelectedItems(i)
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filename)
           
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim lrows As Long
     lrow = wb.Sheets("Gov 1.01 Report").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
     lrows = wb.Sheets("Gov 1.02 Report").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
              
     wb.Activate
        
     wb.Sheets("Gov 1.01 Report").Range("A2:X" & lrow).Copy
                 
      wbk.Sheets("Gov 1.01 Report").Activate
     wbk.Sheets("Gov 1.01 Report").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
     ActiveSheet.Paste
     
     wb.Activate
     wb.Sheets("Gov 1.02 Report").Range("A2:X" & lrows).Copy
              
    wbk.Sheets("Gov 1.02 Report").Activate
    wbk.Sheets("Gov 1.02 Report").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
              
     wb.Close True
                                    
    Next i
    End If
    End With
wbk.Save
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

the above code is for to pull the data from multiple workbooks and paste in the Master workbook within respective sheets. However, when I ran the code, it is closing all the workbooks even Master workbook ( I code it as wbk=thisworkbook). Could you please help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: Could the master file have been selected with the filepicker ? Is the master in the same folder. ?

Comment: Hi, It was in some other folder.... I am selecting the source files only

Comment: Does the master have any code in the `Workbook_AfterSave` sub?

Comment: No It doesn't have such thing

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything in your code that would cause `wbk` to be closed however try this.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub combine()

    Dim wbMaster As Workbook, wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rngSrc As Range
    Dim fDialog As FileDialog, files, filename As String
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long, msg As String
  
    ' get list of files
    Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fDialog
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Title = "Please select the files"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "All supported files", "*.xls*"
        .Filters.Add "Excel files", "*.xls*"
        
        If .Show = True Then
            Set files = .SelectedItems
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    
    ' copy files to master
    Set wbMaster = ThisWorkbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 1 To files.Count
        filename = files(i)
        
        ' open workbook and copy sheets
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filename, False, True) ' no link update, readonly
        For Each ws In wb.Sheets
            If ws.Name Like "Gov 1.0[12] Report" Then
                lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                Set rngSrc = ws.Range("A2:X" & lastrow)
        
                With wbMaster.Sheets(ws.Name)
                    lastrow = .Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                    rngSrc.Copy .Range("A" & lastrow + 1)
                End With
                
                msg = msg & vbLf & wb.Name & " " & ws.Name & " " & rngSrc.Address
            End If
        Next
        wb.Close False
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Copied:" & msg, vbInformation
 
End Sub
```